# How to schedule execution without delay?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-api, airflow-webserver

I have one problem, I need to launch one DAG every first day of month, but I have one problem, the DAG started on 1 October but executed that day on 1 November, I need that 1 October execute 1 October and 1 November execute 1 November, and not delay the execution one month.

My scheduler was: '0 10 1 * *'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Airflow works.
Airflow schedule DAGs at the end of the interval.
So if you have:

```
DAG(
    dag_id='tutorial',
    schedule_interval='0 10 1 * *',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 10, 1),
)
```

The first run will start on `2021-11-01` - this run will have execution date of `2021-10-01`. This behavior is consistent with how data pipelines work. In November you will want to process October data. Or in the terminology that I mentioned before - Your monthly interval starts on beginning of October it ends in November so at the beginning of November you can run the job that process October data.

That said - In the job itself you can process any interval you wish. For that you can use [Airflow macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

In simple words if you want your first DAG run to start on `2021-10-01` you should set `start_date=datetime(2021, 9, 1)`

Starting from Airflow 2.2.0 there was enhancement in that area.
Airflow decoupled the "When to run" from the "What interval to process" with the completion of [AIP- 39 Richer Scheduler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval). You can read about the concept of Timetables in this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html).